# React router OnChange redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to properly implement onChange in my react router. Want I to do is on change I want to redirect to Home. Following this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import Home from './Home';
import Post_Form from './Post_Form';

import * as Firebase from 'firebase';
import Config from './utils/config.js';
import Auth from './utils/auth.js';

import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute  } from 'react-router';

class Root extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    routeChange(nextPathname, nextState, replace, cb) {
      replace({
        pathname: '/home',
        state: {nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname}
      });
      cb();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router history = {browserHistory}>
              <Route path = "/" component = {App} onChange={this.routeChange.bind(this)}>
                 <IndexRoute component = {Home} />
                 <Route path = "home" component = {Home} />
                 <Route path ="post-form" component={Post_Form} />
                 <Route path="*" component={Home}/>
              </Route>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

When click the navigation I get

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the call to replace is triggering another change event and another call to routeChange. That's why your stack size get exceeded.

You can try checking if you are already at home before calling replace. Something like this:

```
if(nextState.location.pathname != '/home'){
      replace({
    pathname: '/home',
    state: {nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname}
  });
    }
```

I do something similar to the above in my project, albeit with onEnter, but I think it should work with onChange as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, all I'm missing is the condition.

Comment: You welcome! Please mark this as the answer if you can :)